# --openssl-legacy-provider with React App, will it cause build/deployment issues down the road?

Tags: reactjs, ssl, heroku, deployment

World!

So as the title says, I have copied a template for a project, it has a bunch of heroku/pg/middleware configs already set up for me.

I have run into the 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED' error when attempting to NPM START.
I know I can downgrade to v16, I just passed the package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=4000 react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build",
```

And this fixed the issue and lets me start normally while still using v18.

I'm worried that down the road this may cause issues during deployment, does anyone have experience with this or a better fix than just the legacy ssl workaround?

Or would one recommend to start fresh and add all the configs myself and not risk it?

Answer (score 1):

I think what could potentially happen is that when node 18 comes to end of life and it's time to update to the latest, you might find that they removed the `--openssl-legacy-provider` option, and you'll have to upgrade whatever package is using legacy openssl.

Since this is a case of "this might be needed later", and it likely will be no more work to do it later than it is now, I think I would say that you can proceed as-is, and if some day down the road you need to address the legacy OpenSSl dependency, you can do so then.